# Refactoring while

Tags: while-loop, lua

Any insights on how to reduce these lines of code (if possible)?

```
local function Run(steps)
    if steps < 0 then
        while steps < 0 do
            Foo()
            steps = steps + 1
        end
    else
        while steps > 0 do
            Bar()
            steps = steps - 1
        end
    end
end

Run(5)
Run(-8)
```

Maybe there is some more efficient way in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten that code but I don't see any reason for it. Code should be easy to read, not as short as possible.

The only thing I would remove is the if statement as the condition is also in the while loops. While loops with known number of iterations based on a counter can be replaced by numeric for loops as Egor already explained.

```
function Run(steps)
  local f = steps < 0 and Foo or Bar
  for i = 1, math.abs(steps) do f() end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You may remove `if` completely.

```
local function Run(steps)
    while steps < 0 do
        Foo()
        steps = steps + 1
    end
    while steps > 0 do
        Bar()
        steps = steps - 1
    end
end

Run(5)
Run(-8)
```

Or you can use `for` loop instead of while:

```
local function Run(steps)
    for i = -1, steps, -1 do
        Foo()
    end
    for i = 1, steps, 1 do
        Bar()
    end
end

Run(5)
Run(-8)
```

But you would not be able to get any measurable performance improvement here.